# Spring Batch - skippable exception in a TaskletStep

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am trying to cause a job not to have `BatchStatus.FAILED` if a certain exception occurs.

The docs talk about using `skippable-exception-classes` within `<chunk>`, but how can I do the same within a `TaskletStep`? The below code does not work:

```
<batch:step id="sendEmailStep">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <bean class="com.myproject.SendEmail" scope="step" autowire="byType">
            <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                <batch:include class="org.springframework.mail.MailException" />
            </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
        </bean>
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I implemented this functionality in the Tasklet as Michael Minella suggested:

```
abstract class SkippableTasklet implements Tasklet {

    //Exceptions that should not cause job status to be BatchStatus.FAILED
    private List<Class<?>> skippableExceptions;

    public void setSkippableExceptions(List<Class<?>> skippableExceptions) {
        this.skippableExceptions = skippableExceptions;
    }

    private boolean isSkippable(Exception e) {
        if (skippableExceptions == null) {
            return false;
        }

        for (Class<?> c : skippableExceptions) {
            if (e.getClass().isAssignableFrom(c)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected abstract void run(JobParameters jobParameters) throws Exception;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext)
            throws Exception {

        StepExecution stepExecution = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution();
        JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
        JobParameters jobParameters = jobExecution.getJobParameters();

        try {
            run(prj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (!isSkippable(e)) {
                throw e;
            } else {
                jobExecution.addFailureException(e);
            }
        }

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

And the Spring XML configuration for an example `SkippableTasklet`:

```
<batch:tasklet>
    <bean class="com.MySkippableTasklet" scope="step" autowire="byType">
        <property name="skippableExceptions">
            <list>
                <value>org.springframework.mail.MailException</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</batch:tasklet>
```

Comment: Why did you create your own step?  The `TaskletStep` handles a lot of background updates and transaction semantics that your step leaves out.  I would *not* recommend this approach.

Comment: Hi Michael, I misread your answer. I changed it to a Tasklet implementation. Does that look ok to you?

Comment: That's more of what I had expected.

Answer (score 3):

Within a `Tasklet`, the responsibility for exception handling is on the implementation of the `Tasklet`.  The skip logic available in chunk oriented processing is due to the exception handling provided by the `ChunkOrientedTasklet`.  If you want to skip exceptions in your own `Tasklet` implementation, you need to write the code to do so in within your own implementation.

Comment: hi, I watch your tutorial about remote chunking. I want to implement skip in there. That use Chunk Oriented Step. How can I implement it in that so it can still read from item reader. Kinda confuse how can I implement the run method for this ` protected abstract void run(JobParameters jobParameters) throws Exception;`

Comment: Please ask a question with this.

Comment: I already ask a question in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788407/implement-skippabletasklet-in-spring-batch-remote-chunking-with-chunk-oriented-p) . please help me with this