# Adding Skippable Exception Classes on Tasklet Impementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

```
<job id="pullPurgeProcessStoreFiles" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <bean id="PullFilesTasklet" class="com.example.PullFilesTasklet" />
         <step id="pullFiles" next="validation" >
            <tasklet ref="PullFilesTasklet">
                <skippable-exception-classes>
                    <include class="java.io.FileNotFoundException"/>
                </skippable-exception-classes>
            </tasklet>  
        </step>     
</job>
```

Getting below Error :
Invalid content was found starting with element `skippable-exception-classes`.

On researching I found that `skippable-exception-classes` can be used within chunks. But I need to achieve the same with ref tasklets.

Comment: by which way I can achieve the same with ref tasklets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to `Skip Exception` in your own `Tasklet` implementation, you need to write the code to do so in within your `Tasklet` own implementation.

Follow this original [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509585/spring-batch-skippable-exception-in-a-taskletstep) and please **Up Vote** on original thread if this solution works for you.

You can do something like

```
abstract class SkippableTasklet implements Tasklet {

    //Exceptions that should not cause job status to be BatchStatus.FAILED
    private List<Class<?>> skippableExceptions;

    public void setSkippableExceptions(List<Class<?>> skippableExceptions) {
        this.skippableExceptions = skippableExceptions;
    }

    private boolean isSkippable(Exception e) {
        if (skippableExceptions == null) {
            return false;
        }

        for (Class<?> c : skippableExceptions) {
            if (e.getClass().isAssignableFrom(c)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected abstract void run(JobParameters jobParameters) throws Exception;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext)
            throws Exception {

        StepExecution stepExecution = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution();
        JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
        JobParameters jobParameters = jobExecution.getJobParameters();

        try {
            run(prj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (!isSkippable(e)) {
                throw e;
            } else {
                jobExecution.addFailureException(e);
            }
        }

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

And in SpringXML configuration

```
<batch:tasklet>
    <bean class="com.MySkippableTasklet" scope="step" autowire="byType">
        <property name="skippableExceptions">
            <list>
                <value>org.springframework.mail.MailException</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</batch:tasklet>
```