# Implement SkippableTasklet in Spring batch remote chunking with Chunk Oriented Processing

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm currently using Spring Batch and want to use remote chunking.

I use chunk oriented processing that use Item Reader, Item Processor and Item Writer and want to implement skip.

I read in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509585/spring-batch-skippable-exception-in-a-taskletstep) that told me to create `SkippableTasklet` but I kinda confuse how to implement `protected abstract void run(JobParameters jobParameters) throws Exception;`

How can I implement skip in this remote chunking implementation?

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways to handle skippable exception. 
I have written this way

```
<batch:step id="sendEmailStep">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <bean class="com.myproject.SendEmail" scope="step" autowire="byType">
            <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                <batch:include class="org.springframework.mail.MailException" />
            </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
        </bean>
    </batch:tasklet>
    <batch:listeners>
        batch:listener ref="skippableListener'/>
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:step>
<bean id="skippableListener" class="SkippableListener/>

public class SkippableListener implements SkipListener
{
   void onSkipInProcess(T item, java.lang.Throwable t){
   //Write your logic
   };
   void onSkipInRead(java.lang.Throwable t){
   //Write your logic
   };
   void onSkipInWrite(S item, java.lang.Throwable t){
   //Write your logic
   };
}
```

Comment: I try and it doesn't work in TaskletStep, this question also say it doesn't work [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509585/spring-batch-skippable-exception-in-a-taskletstep)

Comment: The link gives different solution. That also works fine. My solution is using a listener. This works fine for me and runs in production. Appreciate a up vote.